# Confusion about $L^1$ and $\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, step-function

In my calculus lecture we introduced the following definitions. Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $E$ a normed $\mathbb{R}-$Vektorspace.

- Let $A \in \mathcal{M}, \mu(A) < \infty$ and a finite partition $A = \biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i$ with $A_i \in \mathcal{M}$. $f: X \rightarrow E$ is called *step-function for the partition $(A_i)$ of $A$* if $f|_{A_i}$ is constant for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \not\in A$.
- $T(X,E) := \{f: X \rightarrow E\,|\, f\text{ is step-function for some partition } (A_i) \text{ of some }A \in \mathcal{M}\}$
- $||f||_1 := \int_X f\,d\mu$ defines a Seminorm on $T(X,E)$.
- $L^1(X, E) := \overline{T(X,E) / \{f \in T(X, E) : ||f||_1 = 0\}}$ - the formal completion of the quotient space
- $||\cdot||_1$ is a norm on $L^1(X,E)$.
- $\mathcal{L}^1(X, E)$ is now defined as the set of all $f: X \rightarrow E$ such that there exists an $L^1$-Cauchysequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $T(X,E)$ with $f_n \rightarrow f$ (point-wise) everywhere except on a $\mu$-Nullset.

I *think* with $L^1$-Cauchysequence my professor means Cauchy-Sequence in $||\cdot||_1$-Norm. Now I don't quite understand how $\mathcal{L}^1(X,E)$ and $L^1(X, E)$ differ. The definition with the Cauchy-Sequence seems to produce something like the formal completion and *everywhere except on a $\mu$-Nullset* feels like the Quotient set, but I'm pretty sure $L^1$ and $\mathcal{L}^1$ are not the same.

How it this logically structured? $L^1$ was introduced before $\mathcal{L}^1$...

Comment: I am not sure but in the context of a course this might be because of two technical reasons: 1. you do not know completeness of $L^1$ a priori (before proving it). 2. $\mathcal{L}^1$ are the actual functions defined *pointwise* rather than thinking of them as functions mod null sets.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar Thank you! We know the completeness of $L^1$ as it's defined as the formal competition of the set and I do understand that the elements of $L^1$ are congruence classes and the elements of $\mathcal{L}^1$ are functions, but I don't understand the intuitive (not technical) difference.

Comment: Of course you can take completions of any metric space and it will be complete. The point is, the space in the sense of $\mathcal{L}^1$ is also essentially a complete space (which would be a theorem to be proved). The small technicality is that for it to truly be a normed vector space, you want $\|f\|_1 = 0 \implies f = 0$ which is not true if you distinguish functions which differ on null sets.

Comment: Now you can approach this problem in two ways. One way is to be very strict and formal about this and use equivalences classes and distinguish them from actual functions. The other more common approach is to be more casual and just say $\mathcal{L}^1$ is complete and have an understanding that these functions are all understood to be flexible and just informally consider two things the same if they only differ on null sets. (It's really the same thing but the abuse of notation/terminology in the second approach is easier and quite common)